# Десериализация в dynamic .net core 3.0

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core

Есть необходимость получить объект типа dynamic из Json на .NET Core 3.0:

```
{
    "Name": "Bob",
    "Age": 22
}

dynamic obj = someJsonSer.Deserialize(JsonDataString);
obj.Name; //Bob
obj.Age; //22
```

Близкое по смыслу - JsonDocument (System.Text.Json), но это не совсем то:

```
using(var jDoc = JsonDocument.Parse(response_string))
{
    string foo = jDoc.RootElement.GetProperty("Name").GetString();//Bob
}
```

Json.NET - вариант не желательный.

Какие возможные опции в этой ситуации?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Как я понимаю, во втором примере вас не устраивает то, что вам приходится работать, вызывая различные методы.

В таком случае, вы можете создать класс-наследник от [`ExpandoObject`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.dynamic.expandoobject?view=netframework-4.8), в котором прописать всю необходимую логику поиска свойств в `JsonDocument`.

По моему, по другому никак.

Влез ради интереса в исходники Dapper, что бы посмотреть, как он работает если тип неизвестен и там если вызываешь Qyery, то dapper все кладет в `DapperRow : System.Dynamic.IDynamicMetaObjectProvider`=> по сути-это то, что я и посоветовал сверху.

В JSON.NET, как я понимаю, поддержка `dynamic` [есть](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4535840/deserialize-json-object-into-dynamic-object-using-json-net) из "коробки":

```
dynamic d = JObject.Parse("{number:1000, str:'string', array: [1,2,3,4,5,6]}");

Console.WriteLine(d.number);
Console.WriteLine(d.str);
Console.WriteLine(d.array.Count);
```